# Vaadin Widget does not run the javascript?

Tags: javascript, widget, vaadin

I am a newbie in Vaadin, and writing a Vaadin Widget to show an interactive Map in a page, this a simple javascript I have (it works separately):

```
var showMapToMe = function() {
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'mapid';
div.style.width = "800px";
div.style.height = "800px";
document.body.appendChild(div);
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([ 44.646129, -68.599838 ], 3);   
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=XXXXX',
                {
                    attribution : 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
                    maxZoom : 18,
                }).addTo(mymap);
 L.marker([44.646129, -63.599838]).addTo(mymap);}
```

In the main class, I simply write the following code in the constructor:

```
    @JavaScript({ ".../leaflet.js",".../leaflet.markercluster.js","labMap.js"})
public class MapWidget extends com.vaadin.ui.AbstractJavaScriptComponent {
     public MapWidget() {
        Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("showMapToMe()");
    }
}
```

Finally, in the init function I have:

```
            final MapWidget component = new MapWidget();        
            final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
            layout.setStyleName("demoContentLayout");
            layout.setSizeFull();
            layout.addComponent(component);
            setContent(layout);
```

However, I can not see the map in the page. Did I miss something? Any help?

Comment: I would suggest making your MapWidget to extend VerticalLayout and set it's ID to 'mapid' instead of using JS to create DIV. I would then override the attach method in your MapWidget classs and execut the JS here instead.

Comment: I added layout.setId("mapid"); and deleted DIV, but it did not work.

Comment: Perhaps a bit offtopic, but if at all possible in your case, have you considered using an already existing add-on such as [v-leaflet](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/v-leaflet), [open-layers-wrapper](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/openlayers-3-wrapper-for-vaadin) or [google maps](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/googlemaps-add-on)?

Comment: Yes, I have considered those ones. What if I want to customize the map for a specific purpose.

Comment: There was a chance that you did not know about them. I was merely suggesting that if that were the case, you could easily avoid _reinventing the wheel_ and be done quickly by using it. Otherwise you'd have to go through the trouble of debugging your issue... BTW are you getting any errors in the [developer tools console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) of you choice?

Comment: No error in the console. It shows simply my alert after the line.

Comment: If you used layout.setId("mapid") you would also need to have set the specific size of the div otherwise it would probably not be visible. But as Morifc pointed out, the google maps plugin works really well. It may have enough functionality for you already.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling your function in MapWidget constructor use a connector to do it.

Modify your labMap.js as shown below (or add a new javascript file) and remove code from MapWidget constructor

```
window.com_your_package_MapWidget = function() {

   var showMapToMe = function(div) {   
      // ... your existing code  
   }

   var me = this;
   showMapToMe(me.getElement())
}
```

You can also add a State class so you can initialize attribute in Java code and then use them in the connector script.
See [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/gwt/gwt-javascript.html) for more information